# Flash Player 16 crashes on Firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, flash

Example code:

```
_applicationFileLoader = new Loader();

_applicationFileLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onApplicationLoadProgress, false, 0, true);

private function onApplicationLoadProgress(e:Event):void {
    trace("e.target.bytesTotal: " + e.target.bytesTotal + " e.target.bytesLoaded: " + e.target.bytesLoaded);
}
```

Problem:
bytesTotal = 0 all the time, 
load never completes -> Complete event never fired

also added listeners for:

```
HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS
IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR
Event.INIT
Event.OPEN
Event.UNLOAD
```

but without any hint what could cause the problem

Firefox crashes after a few seconds. 
I have installed Flash Player 16.0.0.287 Debugger, Firefox 35

Is there someone who experienced the same thing?

I'm on a Mac and the console log contains the following message (could not figure out how to format the whole log readable):
[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]

Comment: What you are trying to load ? Local file or remote one ? In local swf file or remote one ? I don't think that these 4 lines can cause a Firefox crash, could you give us more details ?

Comment: FP crashes in browser are often caused by plugins like firebug for example.

Comment: I am trying to load a local .swf file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the release of the update to Firefox 35.0.1.